# How do I represent SQL Server ntuples in first normal form in a schema

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on building Test Case Manager database where each test case can have a set of test steps.

I created a Test Case table, which has as one of its fields a foreign key to the Test Step Groups table. The Test Step Groups table represents  sets of test steps. There is a separate Test Step table to contain rows of test step data.

Each Test Case may contain any number of test steps. I want to be able to re-use sets of test steps, because sometimes test cases re-use sets of steps and then add on other steps. It's not a hierarchical structure, of course, more of an n-tuple structure.

So how do I define in the schema a representation of a Test Case with any number of test steps?

Comment: Here's the idea:
TestCase ---->  TestGroup ------> Step1, Step2, Step3, etc.

Comment: not sure i fully follow, but sounds like you might need a link table between `TestCase` and `TestCaseGroup` so there is no direct link between a group and a case.

Comment: I'm not allowed to post images. Darn!

Comment: @Tanner: There is an ID field linking the case to the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to reuse the `groups` and `steps` for your test cases I think you will need 2 linking tables between your 3 entities, so that the cases aren't tied to groups and groups aren't tied to steps.

Something along the lines of this might provide you with a dummy scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_case
    (
      case_id INT ,
      case_name VARCHAR(10)
    )
CREATE TABLE #temp_case_group
    (
      case_id INT ,
      group_id INT
    )
CREATE TABLE #temp_group ( group_id INT )
CREATE TABLE #temp_group_steps
    (
      group_id INT ,
      step_id INT
    )
CREATE TABLE #temp_steps
    (
      step_id INT ,
      step_name VARCHAR(10)
    )

INSERT  INTO #temp_case
        ( case_id, case_name )
VALUES  ( 1, 'CASE 1' ),
        ( 2, 'CASE 2' ),
        ( 3, 'CASE 3' )

INSERT  INTO #temp_case_group
        ( case_id, group_id )
VALUES  ( 1, 6 ),
        ( 2, 6 ),
        ( 3, 7 )

INSERT  INTO #temp_group
        ( group_id )
VALUES  ( 6 ),
        ( 7 )

INSERT  INTO #temp_group_steps
        ( group_id, step_id )
VALUES  ( 6, 10 ),
        ( 6, 11 ),
        ( 6, 14 ),
        ( 7, 10 ),
        ( 7, 12 ),
        ( 7, 14 )

INSERT  INTO #temp_steps
        ( step_id, step_name )
VALUES  ( 10, 'first step' ),
        ( 11, 'foo step' ),
        ( 12, 'bar step' ),
        ( 14, 'last step' )


SELECT  tc.case_id ,
        tc.case_name ,
        tg.group_id ,
        ts.step_id ,
        ts.step_name
FROM    #temp_case tc
        INNER JOIN #temp_case_group tcg ON tcg.case_id = tc.case_id
        INNER JOIN #temp_group tg ON tg.group_id = tcg.group_id
        INNER JOIN #temp_group_steps tgs ON tgs.group_id = tg.group_id
        INNER JOIN #temp_steps ts ON ts.step_id = tgs.step_id
ORDER BY tc.case_id ,
        tcg.group_id ,
        ts.step_id

DROP TABLE #temp_case
DROP TABLE #temp_case_group
DROP TABLE #temp_group
DROP TABLE #temp_group_steps
DROP TABLE #temp_steps
```

**Output:**

```
case_id  case_name  group_id    step_id  step_name
1        CASE 1     6           10       first step
1        CASE 1     6           11       foo step
1        CASE 1     6           14       last step
2        CASE 2     6           10       first step
2        CASE 2     6           11       foo step
2        CASE 2     6           14       last step
3        CASE 3     7           10       first step
3        CASE 3     7           12       bar step
3        CASE 3     7           14       last step
```

So you can see, `CASE 1` and `CASE 2` share the same group, and therefore contain the same steps. `CASE 3` uses it's own group but shares the first and last step with the other group.

This will allow groups of steps to be reused on different test cases, and allow steps to be reused across different groups, which is hopefully what you're after.

Comment: You are a SQL King! Thank you very much.

Comment: @SuLlewellyn hardly, but thanks. Saw that you were new and wanted to give you a good welcome to the site.